# Login form validation on CakePHP app

Tags: cakephp

I have added the following validation to my User model:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $useTable = 'users';

    var $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'rule'=>array('minLength', 1), 
            'message'=>'Please enter your username' ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule'=>array('minLength', 1), 
            'message'=>'Please enter your password' )
    );
}
```

The idea is that if a user doesn't fill out the fields on the login form then it will show the messages above. However it doesn't work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should actually use is the ['notEmpty'](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1152/Core-Validation-Rules#notEmpty-1173), set ['allowEmpty'](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field) to false and ensure it is ['required'](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field#required-1147)

```
var $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a username'
    )
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Please enter a password'
    )
);
```

Update:

Bit of a hack, but change the name of your login form to 'UserLogin' - then in your before filter check if $this->data['UserLogin'] is set. If it is - check if $this->data['UserLogin']['username'] is empty, if so just set a flash saying its empty. Same goes for password.

Comment: Whoops! Didn't read the title this time - for your login form it is actually again bad practice to offer any feedback; again any hackers may use it to know what sort of validation is in place and making it easier to bruteforce. Probably why cake won't let you display errors.

Comment: My client has requested to see validation (server-side) if the user sends a blank form though so I need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Updated with a way to do it. Not the best and not recommended!